# How to store multiple images for each user using picker into core data?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, swift, core-data

I am facing a problem in storing multiple images tagged to one user or one location using Core Data.

What is the best practice in storing images or other media types? Does Core Data work just fine with big binary data such as images or media?

Comment: "I am facing a problem", it would be helpful to tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

here is the func....

func showImagePickerWithAssetType(assetType: DKImagePickerControllerAssetType,
        allowMultipleType: Bool = true,
        sourceType: DKImagePickerControllerSourceType = [.Camera, .Photo]) {

```
        let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
        pickerController.assetType = assetType
        pickerController.allowMultipleTypes = allowMultipleType
        pickerController.sourceType = sourceType

        pickerController.didCancelled = {
            print("didCancelled")
        }

        pickerController.didSelectedAssets = { [unowned self] (assets: [DKAsset]) in
            print("didSelectedAssets")
            print(assets.map({ $0.url}))

            self.assets = assets
            self.previewView?.reloadData()
        }

        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true) {}
}
```